# In the Unity editor, why are the coordinates of a newly created root object not set to 0,0,0 when the object is at the origin?

Tags: unity, transformation

My initial coordinates of a newly created object without a parent are not 0,0,0

They’re supposed to be at the origin. Instead they are some random number.

And how can I set them to zero without moving the object to some arbitrary location?
I tried changing local to global in the scene, but it didnt affect those.

What caused them to be these random numbers?
The floor is centered at (0,0,0)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is, you spawned the object over the top menu. This will spawn the object in the center of your current view. It would make sense from a design point of view to have the new created object close to further manipulate it - in a big scene, 0/0/0 can be quite far from the current working location.

The same happens when you right click in the hierarchy. It will still spawn at the current center.

If you right click on the scene and spawn it from there, it will be created at 0/0/0.

Comment: You can move the object to 0, 0, 0 and then press thr F key on your keyboard to "focus" the scene view on it. Then the next object you spawn at view center will go to 0, 0, 0 as expected. As to why thr offset position looks centered in your room, that's either an illusion, or the room itself is not centered at 0, 0, 0 as you thought.